# How to disable a button from start up (visual c# winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Title says it all. If I write

> tryGuessButton.Enabled = false;

It will still allow me to press the button on start up. I wrote that under the button control though. Should I write it somewhere else to disable it from start up? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want the button disabled from the start, just set the property in the designer. Compile the form that way.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Enabled property on the designer or you can do it probably on the constructor of the form after the `InitializeComponents()`

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    tryGuessButton.Enabled = false;
}
```